# Powershell workflow - Restart a server after windows updates installation

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, workflow, windows-update

I am building a Powershell Workflow to install several patches including Windows Updates on several remote windows servers and then perform some follow up tasks. I can Use

```
Restart-Computer -Wait -For WinRm
```

to restart a remote server and wait for it to be accessible again. However, this is a caveat especially for Windows Server 2008 R2 as sometimes it needs more than a reboot to finish off the installation and I've found that between these reboots WinRm sometimes starts, letting the job/workflow to continue, but then it restarts again or does not allow RDP connections as it's still busy installing/finishing off installation (http://woshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Preparing-to-configure-Windows-Do-not-turn-off-your-computer.jpg).

I was wondering which kind of check could I put in place to make sure a remote server is really accessible after windows patches installation. For example, what kind of process or service should I wait or monitor to make sure the server is really accessible again? (https://forums.nomachine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Connection-to-99.135.58.49-02182014-01.09.07.png)

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Did you find a solution? facing the same issue

Comment: Apparently using Restart-Computer with the optional switches -Wait -For Powershell it's enough to let the computer restart and wait for WiinRM/Powershell to be available to continue the script/workflow